# How to prevent TableModel from firing table changed event?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

NOTE: This is for a drawing tool application

I currently have `JTable` that has a `tableChanged()` event.

```
coFigureTable[i].getModel().addTableModelListener(
            new TableModelListener()
{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        coCanvas.userSetCoords(figIndex, angle, row, column);
    }
}
```

The table contains x and y coordinates , and an angle of a figure. The user can manually changed these values. When an angle value is changed in the `coFigureTable`, the figure in the Canvas will rotate. However, when a rotation happens, all coordinates must be also updated in the table which happens in `userSetCoords` function. So I call `repaint()` for the table to update the values. This fires a table changed event that results to the movement of the figure and so on. Thus, an infinite loop.

How can I prevent calling table changed once it is already done once? Or is there another event or algorithm that can remedy this problem?

Comment: If you have to call `repaint()` to update the table, something else is wrong. Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a flag when you are updating things, so that your `TableModelListener`
knows to ignore the event.

```
boolean isUpdatingUI = false;

void initialise(){
  coFigureTable[i].getModel().addTableModelListener(
    new TableModelListener(){
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)    {
            if(!isUpdatingUI)
               coCanvas.userSetCoords(figIndex, angle, row, column);
        }
  }
}

public void doUpdate(){
   isUpdatingUI = true; 
   coFigureTable[i].getModel().setValue( ..... );  // update table
   isUpdatingUI = false;
}
```

The flag should be a class member.

PS it isn't a good idea to update data in a `paint` method.

Though ideally the update should occur in the GUI thread, so that if a user concurrently changes the table, the interface edits don't get ignored.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I already tried using a flag. It worked just fine but once `isUpdatingUI` is set to `false`, the user cannot make the figure rotate again. I forgot to mention that there are multiple figures to rotate. And the user can rotate these figures in an unlimited number of times.

Comment: Well you haven't shown enough of your own code to allow me to help you on this! It seems that the error is somewhere we can't see. The method above should work for what you describe. Why don't you step through with a debugger? I.e. update the data, set a breakpoint, then try rotating again to see if `isUpdatingUI` is really `false` - and why the rotate code is not called. If this doesn't work, try posting a more complete code example (i.e. one that actually runs).